# Solve $ x^2 + \bar{2}x - \bar{2} = \bar{0} $ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

> Solve $ x^2 + \bar{2}x - \bar{2} = \bar{0} $ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

I could try plugging in $\bar{0}, \bar{1}, ..., \bar{10}$ and see if I get a solution, however, this method seems too slow and "brute force". Are there other methods for solving this equation?

Can I use the quadratic formula to solve this? Anyway, using the quadratic formula you get the term

$$\sqrt{-\bar{4}}$$

And I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: You can't use the quadratic formula blindly. You could however stare at the proof of the quadratic formula and follow its guidance.

Comment: @AlfredYerger But we can - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\!\bmod 11\!:\ $ the discriminant is $\,\color{#c00}{\sqrt{12}}\equiv \sqrt{1}\equiv 1\equiv \color{#0a0}{12},\ $ hence the

quadratic formula $\, \Rightarrow\, x \equiv \dfrac{-2\pm\color{#c00}{\sqrt{12}}}2\,\equiv\, \dfrac{-2\pm \color{#0a0}{12}}2\equiv -1\pm 6\equiv 5,4,\,$ by $\, -7\equiv 4$

Comment: On my phone right now, how did you arrive at the discriminant $\sqrt{12}$? Doing with the coefficients of the equation you get sqrt{-4}

Comment: @VictorS $\ \ b^2-4ac = 2^2-4(1)(-2) = 4+8 = \color{#c00}{12},\ $ It looks like you have a sign error in your calculation: $\,4-8\,$ vs. $\,4+8\ \ $

Comment: Indeed I made a sign error or I used a wrong quadratic formula, probably the first as I was tired.. thank you anyway for a solution with the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 4):

Modulo $11$, we have: 
$$
x^2 + 2x - 2 = x^2 + 2x + 1  - 3 = (x + 1)^2  - 3.
$$
Now, does $3$ have any square roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$?  Yes:
$$
5^2 = 25 \equiv 3 \mbox{ mod } 11.
$$
So, 
$$
(x + 1)^2  - 5^2,
$$
a difference of two squares.

Comment: I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: It's $x + 2x -2$, not $x - 2x - 2$

Comment: @VictorS., I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @VictorS. We can also use the quadratic formula - see my answer.